# Can I do a Ranking script with instagram Followers count

Tags: php, mysql, instagram, ranking

I already have a ranking system on my site

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT   `page`,`img`,`Name`,`item`, (`totalrate` / `nrrates`),
         @rank_count := @rank_count + (totalrate/nrrates < @prev_value) rank,
         @prev_value := totalrate/nrrates avg
FROM     rtgitems, (SELECT @prev_value := NULL, @rank_count := 1) init
WHERE item REGEXP 'Total' ORDER BY avg DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

I want to rank several selected celebrities on their Instagram follower count
and rank them based on who has the most Instagram followers

1. Is it possible to do this?
2. Is there a limit on the request count?, eg can I have 100-1000 celebrities ranked

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it is possible. But not with only one Instagram API request.
2. Unfortunatelly it's only possible to get one user info per request. If you need 100-1000 celebrities, you should have this list organized (with instagram ids) and execute a loop through it to perform 100-1000 requests to Instagram API using this endpoint:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

The response will look like this

```
{
"data": {
    "id": "1574083",
    "username": "snoopdogg",
    "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
    "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1574083_75sq_1295469061.jpg",
    "bio": "This is my bio",
    "website": "http://snoopdogg.com",
    "counts": {
        "media": 1320,
        "follows": 420,
        "followed_by": 3410
    }
}
```

You should save **data->counts->followed_by** for each user and then execute a query ordered by those numbers.

I recommend to implement a little waiting period between requests (**sleep(t)** in php) to avoid Instagram understand your requests as a DOS attack and block you.

3. You didn't ask, but you probably know only the username of the celebrities. To get their Instagram IDs you need to perform a search for users using the exact username using this endpoint:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q={username}&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

Considering you're using the exact username, the first result will be the user you're looking for. The response will look like this (using q=jack):

```
{
"data": [{
    "username": "jack",
    "first_name": "Jack",
    "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_66_75sq.jpg",
    "id": "66",
    "last_name": "Dorsey"
},
{
    "username": "sammyjack",
    "first_name": "Sammy",
    "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_29648_75sq_1294520029.jpg",
    "id": "29648",
    "last_name": "Jack"
},
{
    "username": "jacktiddy",
    "first_name": "Jack",
    "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_13096_75sq_1286441317.jpg",
    "id": "13096",
    "last_name": "Tiddy"
}]
}
```

Save **data[0]->id** to your database so you can perform the user info request later.

Good luck.